# Problem with theorems numeration

Tags: numbering, theorems

Good morning members of the community. I am preparing a document and the same problem of enumeration in the theorems always arises. In this case I do not know how to do so that the first proposition comes out labeled as proposition 2.1 (which would be the right thing). I'd appreciate your help. I attach the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2.cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\title{Teorema de Banach-Alaouglu-Bourbaki}
\author{Diego Patiño}
\markright{ {\small {\it Análisis funcional}}}
\date{Enero 2019}
\pagestyle{myheadings}


\newtheorem{Def}[subsection]{Definición}
\newtheorem{cor}[subsection] {Corolario}
\newtheorem{lem}[subsection]{Lema}
\newtheorem{prop}[subsection]{Proposicion}
\newtheorem{teo}[subsection] {Teorema}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Se sabe que la bola unitaria cerrada de un espacio vectorial de dimensión 
infinita no es compacta, de hecho, un espacio vectorial $E$ es finito 
dimensional si y solamente si la bola cerrada unitaria en $E$ es compacta. 
El problema radica entonces en controlar esta situación, debilitando la 
topología con la cuál dotamos el espacio, lo que permite tener menos 
abiertos y al mismo tiempo ganar más conjuntos compactos. El precio a pagar 
por este debilitamiento es que el número de funciones continuas disminuye, 
en comparación con la ganancia de compactos...\\



\section{Preliminares}
A continuación se darán algunas definiciones y resultados útiles de 
topología general:

\begin{Def}[Función contínua] Una función $f:X\to Y$ entre espacios 
topológicos es \textit{continua} si el conjunto 
\begin{equation*}
  f^{-1}(A):=\{x\in X:f(x)\in A\}
\end{equation*}
es abierto en $X$ para todo abierto $A$ en $Y$
\end{Def}

\begin{prop}
Las siguientes afie

\end{prop}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you define your theorem environments as `\newtheorem{Def}{Definición}[section]` and then `\newtheorem{cor}[Def]{Corolario}`, `\newtheorem{lem}[Def]{Lema}` etc. they'll share a counter. So after "Definition 2.1" you'll get "Proposition 2.2". It's a personal preference, but I find that this makes the document easier to navigate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make all `\newtheorem` definition as, for example, `\newtheorem{prop}{Proposicion}[section]`.

```
\newtheorem{Def}{Definición}[section]
\newtheorem{cor} {Corolario}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lema}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposicion}[section]
\newtheorem{teo} {Teorema}[section]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! @ferahfeza. It was very useful for me. I have learned something new. I see that my error was in the order of the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

The optional argument used in *second* position is for counters of other theorem-like environments, to mean they share the same counter. Resetting to 1 the theorem-like counter at every (sub)section  uses the (sub)section counter as an optional argument in *third* position.

Also beware that if the numbering is reset at each *subsection* the theorem numbers will be made up of 3 numbers (section  no.subsection no.theorem no):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\title{Teorema de Banach-Alaouglu-Bourbaki}
\author{Diego Patiño}
\markright{ {\small {\it Análisis funcional}}}
\date{Enero 2019}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

\newtheorem{Def}{Definición}[subsection]
\newtheorem{cor} {Corolario}[subsection]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lema}[subsection]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposicion}[subsection]
\newtheorem{teo} {Teorema}[subsection]
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Se sabe que la bola unitaria cerrada de un espacio vectorial de dimensión
infinita no es compacta, de hecho, un espacio vectorial $E$ es finito
dimensional si y solamente si la bola cerrada unitaria en $E$ es compacta.
El problema radica entonces en controlar esta situación, debilitando la
topología con la cuál dotamos el espacio, lo que permite tener menos
abiertos y al mismo tiempo ganar más conjuntos compactos. El precio a pagar
por este debilitamiento es que el número de funciones continuas disminuye,
en comparación con la ganancia de compactos...\\

\section{Preliminares}
A continuación se darán algunas definiciones y resultados útiles de
topología general:

\begin{Def}[Función contínua] Una función $f:X\to Y$ entre espacios
topológicos es \textit{continua} si el conjunto
\begin{equation*}
  f^{-1}(A):=\{x\in X:f(x)\in A\}
\end{equation*}
es abierto en $X$ para todo abierto $A$ en $Y$
\end{Def}

\begin{prop}
Las siguientes afie
\end{prop}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bernard. I see there are other ways to list the theorems.